# Порядок задания аргументов в функцию. Почему нужно именно так?

Tags: функции, синтаксис, параметры, стандарт, семантика

Недавно задумался о красоте своего кода.

Большой вопрос у меня встал тогда, когда мне показалось, что аргументы в функции должны идти в ином порядке, ежели сейчас. 
Возьмём, например, функцию (на С++, но здесь язык особой роли не играет, вопрос в другом):

`int FindСitу (string *СitiеsList, string сity_nаmе, int сitiеs_cоunt);`

Функция возвращает `id` города (из массива `СitiеsList` длиной `сitiеs_cоunt`), имя которого `сity_nаmе`.

В каком порядке лучше записать аргументы этой функции? Как бы поступили вы, и почему? Есть ли какой-то стандарт по правильному размещению аргументов функций?

Comment: я бы поставил имя города первым аргументом, а массив вторым, потому что хотел бы подчеркнуть что мы ищем, а не где

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Единого стандарта конечно же нет, но я бы сказал, что в 9 случаев из 10 параметры `СitiеsList` и `сitiеs_cоunt` шли бы подряд.
А в 99 из 100 случаев имена были бы записаны однообразно: `СitiеsList` и `СitiеsСоunt`, или `citiеsList` и `citiеsСоunt`, или `citiеs_list` и `citiеs_cоunt`.

Язык программирования конечно же важен, и часто существуют официальные рекомендации по стилю кода для конкретного языка, но зачастую условия диктуют так же конкретные фреймворки, библиотеки, платформы, их соблюдение является даже более приоритетным.

Также нужно понимать, что для англоязычного программиста программа пишется почти на родном языке, и существует естественное желание заменить

```
удалить(базаДанных, запись)
```

на более осмысленное

```
удалить(запись, базаДанных)
```

Но зачастую однообазие `api` важнее

```
количество(базаДанных)
вставить(базаДанных, запись1, запись2...)
```

В функциональных языках программирования стараются еще больше приблизить программу к естественному языку, например в `Scala`

```scala
1 to 10 by 2 map (_ * 2) // Vector(2, 6, 10, 14, 18)
```

это всего лишь альтернативная форма записи для цепочки применения

```scala
1.to(10).by(2).map(x => x * 2)
```

а в `Haskell` каррирование, частичное применение и инфиксная форма применения функций позволяют делать подобные вещи

```hs
Prelude> on f g x y = g x `f` g y
Prelude> add x y = x + y
Prelude> mul x y = x * y
Prelude> addOnMul10 = add `on` mul 10
Prelude> addOnMul10 3 7
100
```

Это тоже накладывает ограничения на порядок аргументов.

В общем, используйте порядок, который считаете естественным, но с оглядкой на то, как делают другие - излишний индивидуализм скорее вреден.